# Why am I not able to add an HTML Classname to an Element Collection using MSXML2 with VBA

Tags: html, vba, collections, element, classname

I have tried many proven methods from various posts to get some data from a web page without success. I am able to get a list of linked items on the opening page but once I navigate to any other page, I draw a blank with the code below.

When I run the code, I get no results in Cats.

```
Sub Main()
Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Dim Cats As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim Cat As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim NextHref As String
Dim NextURL As String

XMLReq.Open "GET", URL, False
XMLReq.send

If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
    MsgBox "Problem"
    Exit Sub
End If

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText
Set XMLReq = Nothing

Set Cats = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("ng-tns-c329-5 product-grid--tile ng-star-inserted")

Debug.Print Cats.Length 'Returns 0

'For Each Cat In Cats
'    NextHref = Cat.getAttribute("href")
'    NextURL = URL & Mid(NextHref, InStr(NextHref, ":") + 2)
'    ListItemsInCats Cat.innerText, NextURL

'Next Cat

End Sub
```

[Expanded Element structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0Jfb.png)

[Collased structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D4Yt.png)

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: What's the URL in question? My guess it's Woolworth from some googling but what's the exact URL for the "opening page"? The data came from API so you won't find anything from the HTML document.

Comment: Thanks Raymond. The complete for the opening page is = URL is https://www.woolworths.com.au. The navigated page is = https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/browse/bakery

Comment: Can you clarify what information are you looking for in each product? Just the name and price (If discounted, non-discount or discounted price?) of the product?

Comment: Ye Raymond. Thats exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I am wanting to put together a list of product and compare them with other outlets as a camparison and subsequent savings.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't seems to get a response from the API as it returns `Access denied` error. It might be resolvable but I have no knowledge on how to do that currently. The alternative which might work is to use IE to open the webpage and scrape the HTML which is alot slower.

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to when you say you are getting Access Denied error. 
I have also tried with IE but continue to get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the website you are trying to scrape from is that:

In XMLHTTP Request method - The product details are dynamic content that is pulled from Fetch/XHR which XMLHTTP does not run, XMLHTTP only gives you the HTML document as it is without any script running.

In Internet Explorer method - The webpage is considered ready before the product details are actually loaded so the usual loop check for `Busy` and `ReadyState` is not sufficient.

The code below uses Internet Explorer and to resolve the issue mentioned above, I have put up some checks (Which is not perfect I believe but it works so far in my testing) that will wait until the first product has been loaded before proceeding to pull the product details:

```
Private Sub GetBakeryProducts()
    Const URL As String = "https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/browse/bakery"
    
    Dim ieObj As InternetExplorer
    Set ieObj = New InternetExplorer
    
    ieObj.navigate URL
    ieObj.Visible = True
    
    Do While ieObj.Busy Or ieObj.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    Do While ieObj.document.getElementsByClassName("productCarousel-header").Length = 0
        DoEvents
    Loop
        
    Dim ieDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set ieDoc = ieObj.document

    Dim productList As Object
    Set productList = ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("product-grid--tile")
        
    '==== Test if the website has finish loading the 1st product details
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim testStatus As String
    Do
        Err.Clear
        testStatus = productList(0).getElementsByClassName("shelfProductTile-descriptionLink")(0).innerText
    Loop Until Err.Number = 0
    '====
    
    Dim outputArr() As String
    ReDim outputArr(1 To productList.Length, 1 To 2) As String
    Dim outputIndex As Long
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To productList.Length - 1
        If productList(i).getElementsByClassName("shelfProductTile-descriptionLink").Length <> 0 Then
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                Err.Clear
                Exit For
            End If
            
            Dim productName As String
            Dim productPrice As String
            
            productName = productList(i).getElementsByClassName("shelfProductTile-descriptionLink")(0).innerText
            productPrice = Replace(productList(i).getElementsByClassName("price")(0).innerText, vbNewLine, vbNullString)
            
            outputIndex = outputIndex + 1
            outputArr(outputIndex, 1) = productName
            outputArr(outputIndex, 2) = productPrice
        End If
    Next i
    
    ReDim Preserve outputArr(1 To outputIndex, 1 To 2) As String
    
    ieObj.Quit
    Set ieObj = Nothing
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(outputIndex, UBound(outputArr, 2)).Value = outputArr
End Sub
```

Running this will pull the data from the website and paste the output starting from cell `A1` in `Sheet1`, please change the worksheet name and range as you see fits.

Comment: @QHarr Thanks for highlighting this, I forgot to mention that I was actually referring to his comment to me saying that he tried with IE but with same result. You are right that his issue in his question is due to the XHR request not being made in xmlhttp.

Comment: @QHarr Have edited to elaborate on issue for both methods, thank!

Comment: thanks to all who have put time in to assist with this.
The code provided does the job beit on the slower side but there are times we need to compramise.
Great effort. Thanks you.

Comment: @John If an answer resolves your question, you are encouraged to accept it by clicking the tick beside it (You can only accept one if there are multiple answers).

Comment: Why do I not see a tick anywhere?

Comment: @John it's at the top-left side of the answer.